# Specializing non-trivial primality tests

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

Primes $p$ are integers with no factors (composite allowed) in $[1,p]$. There is a polynomial time test for them.

Given an interval $[a,b]$ what is the best way to test given integer $q$ has no composite factor allowed in $[a,b]$? Can any non-trivial primality test be specialized?

Comment: If a+2 is less than b+2 is less than a+a, start with gcd(q,c) where c = b choose a-1.  Otherwise split the interval up.  Gerhard "Best Way Known To Me" Paseman, 2017.11.04.

Comment: $c=\binom{b}{a-1}$ could be large (say $a=5\times 10^{100}, b=6\times 10^{100}$ (also I do not get why use $gcd(q,c)$))?

Comment: @Turbo The very first step of the euclidean algorithm is replacing c with c modulo q. So you can just compute the binomial coefficient modulo q in the first place to avoid that particular problem.

Comment: @JohannesHahn 1. I would not know how to compute binomial coefficients mod $q$ in poly time. 2. I do not know why this is useful at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking whether an integer $n$ has a divisor in a given interval is essentially equivalent to factorization. Factoring is essentially equivalent to finding the smallest prime factor. So suppose that $n$ is not prime. Then check whether $n$ has a prime factor in $[1, n^{1/4}]$. Depending on the outcome check whether $n$ has a factor in $[1, n^{1/8}]$ or in $[n^{1/4}, n^{3/8}]$. After $\frac{\log n}{\log 2}$ steps you have determined the smallest prime factor of $n$. So as far as we know, checking for factors in an arbitrary interval is a lot more difficult than checking for factors in $[2, n-1]$.

Comment: "Checking whether an integer $n$ has a divisor in a given interval is essentially equivalent to factorization" no it is not.

Comment: @Turbo And what is unclear to you in Jan-Christoph's proof that indeed it is?

Comment: how is it equivalent to factoring? it is harder than factoring. He gives one reduction. He reduces factoring to finding no factors in an interval. He only proves the new problem is at least as hard as factoring which is implicit in the question as I may have very well given $q$ along all its prime factors and the difficulty morally remains similar.

Comment: Is the factor $\log n$ bothering you?

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta your answer does not relate to the problem.

Comment: If you assume that the prime factorization of $n$ is given, then your question becomes a knapsack problem. There are many different algorithms for this problem, you should ask in combinatorial optimization.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta is 'combinatorial optimization' the only way?

Comment: "The only way" may be too strong a statement, but all known primality tests associate a group $G(n)$ to a number $n$ and compare this group to what it would look like if $n$ was prime. If they are sufficiently similar, then $n$ must be prime.